# PhpStorm Fatal error: Class 'Crypt_RSA' not found (phpseclib)

Tags: php, phpstorm, phpseclib

I'm trying to add phpseclib as external library in PhpStorm.

I've downloaded phpseclib from GitHub, extracted files and added phpseclib here: `Settings | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Include Path`.

After that `$phpsec = new Crypt_RSA();` and run but gives me this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Crypt_RSA' not found `

After that I've tried these lines:

```
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib');
include('Net/SSH2.php');
include("Crypt/RSA.php");
```

Gives me these errors:

```
Warning: include(Net/SSH2.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Net/SSH2.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:phpseclib')
Warning: include(Crypt/RSA.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Crypt/RSA.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:phpseclib') 
Fatal error: Class 'Crypt_RSA' not found
```

Also tried this:

```
include('library/php/Crypt/RSA.php');
```

Gave same errors.

What is the true method to add phpseclib library and use it.

My main purpose is RSA OAEP public encryption with sha256.

Comment: 1) Adding a library in `Settings/Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Include Path` does it for IDE only (so it can index it if it's outside of the project folder) -- it does not affect actual code execution at all. 2) You need to properly include that library in your code (`include`/`require`) in order for PHP to use it. Just use proper path

Comment: @LazyOne I'm new on php and phpstorm can u explain little bit to include / require ?

Comment: So far the issue is about PHP code -- how to correctly include phpseclib. `include('library/php/Crypt/RSA.php');` -- this is right approach -- just use correct path to the file (relative to the current file or project root folder .. or absolute path).

Comment: Where did you put the phpseclib files? Like what's the full URL? The `PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib'` bit expects phpseclib to be in a phpseclib directory within the current directory. If you're having difficulty with the include_path you might be better off trying to install phpseclib 2.0 through Composer.

Comment: @neubert at last i put phpseclib on project root folder after that with minor adjustments I called encrypt method successfully. Now im not sure how to encrypt RSA OAEP public encryption with sha256 with my public key

Comment: Try this: https://pastebin.com/PJr4xbDS

Comment: @neubert i did same way but always gives different output for same plaintext is that normal   ?

Comment: @BMErEr - yah - that's how it's supposed to work. OAEP padding has a random component to it to prevent known plaintext attacks (wherein if you send the same message twice an attacker wouldn't have any way of knowing that)

Answer (score 0):

> Failed opening 'Crypt/RSA.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear:phpseclib')

It seems that Yours `PATH_SEPARATOR` is `:` instead of `/`. Change:

`set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'phpseclib');` to

`set_include_path(get_include_path() .'/phpseclib');`
or set Your `PATH_SEPARATOR` to `/`.

Comment: @BMErEr In which way it doesn't work? Is there something changed? Primarily the path in Yours include path is correct one?

Comment: i don't understand linux. but phpseclib is  on my desktop and i add it from settings ... as i said above. (I trıed full path to)